# Why is swaddling good for your heath?

Tags: stress

There are [many](https://nypost.com/2017/08/23/stressed-out-adults-are-paying-people-to-swaddle-them/), [many](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-38441166) articles on this, but I was wounding what the facts were on this. There's a lot of talk that it is good for your health, but I have not found any evidence that it actually is.

Swaddling adults is said to help provide stress-relief and similar effects to that of swaddling babies is said to calm them, making them feel lie they are in the womb.

So, why is swaddling believed to be  good for your heath?

Comment: People believe lots of things for no good reason, especially when it comes to health matters.